# Callback event when jQuery 'mmenu' closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, mmenu

Using the [jQuery mmenu plugin](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/), I need to call a JavaScript function either after the menu has finished closing or simultaneously.
In the documentation I can't see any suggestion for closing entire menu but only for [closePanel](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/api.html).
I need to insert in mmenu closing function another one (custom) to hide lightbox effect on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu").mmenu({
    "extensions": [
    "theme-white"
    ],
    "offCanvas": {
        "zposition": "front"
    },
    "slidingSubmenus": false
});
$("#menu").show();
});   
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function lightbox(){    
(function($) {      
  // some stuff
})(jQuery);}
</script>
```

is there a way to bind another function after the plugin has been closed or better, when entire menu closing action?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact question today and after some tinkering, this works for me. Bind to the opened/closed events like so:

```js
$('#mmenu_id').data('mmenu').bind('opened', function () {
    console.log('opened');
});
$('#mmenu_id').data('mmenu').bind('closed', function () {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

Comment: This event is after the panel has closed... If you want the event to occur as soon as you request the closing, what do you do then?

Comment: This may help, http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/api.html I don't see an event available for binding before the action. You could attach an event listener to the close button itself?

Comment: The "atmd" answer states the event "closing", which works perfectly. Thanks man.

Comment: take into account that there are also "opening" and "closing" events

Answer (score 4):

you could try binding to the closing event

```
$('#mmenu').on('closing.mm', function() {
    // do something
});
```

There is also a closed event too, so you can use which ever is appropriate

```
$('#mmenu').on('closed.mm', function() {
    // do something
});
```